# How can I get a longer calculation?

Tags: economics

This is the example that my teacher gave in my economic class. I will write the formula and equation with the given answer below. Actually my teacher already calculate the example table of (modified internal rate of return - mirr). The only thing that I don't know is how to use the formula or get the answer even though the answer is already given.

Example

Formula for Compound Amount

S = P (1+i)^n,

i = 12%

Answer

Product F

16,431.7 = 9000(1+i)^4
= 16.24%

MY PROBLEM

The problem is can you show me the exact longer way to get those '16.24%'? I know that I'm stupid but please help me. I'm really can't remember how to calculate it.

*what should I do with that '16431.7'?
*how to get that '16.24%'?

Comment: Do you see $(1+i)^4 = 16431.7/9000$? Now take the fourth root from both sides.

Answer (score 2):

Given $P=9000$, $i=12\,\%$, $n=4$, we first write $12\,\%$ as $\frac {12}{100}$ and then compute
$$ \begin{align}S&=P\cdot (1+i)^n\\&=9000\cdot\left(1+\frac{12}{100}\right)^4\\&=9000\cdot 1.12^4 \\&= 9000\cdot 1.57351936 \\&= 14161.67424\end{align}$$
which I do not see in your post.

Perhaps, your actual task rather was: Given $S=16431.7$, $P=9000$, $n=4$, find $i$?
For this, transform the orignal equation:
$$P\cdot (1+i)^n=S$$
$$ (1+i)^n= \frac SP$$
$$ 1+i = \sqrt[n]{\frac SP}$$
$$ i = \sqrt[n]{\frac SP}-1$$
so
$$ \begin{align}i&=\sqrt[4]\frac{16431.7}{9000}-1 \\&\approx\sqrt[4]{\strut1.82574}-1\\&\approx 1.1624-1\\&=0.1624\\&=16.24\,\%  \end{align}$$

Comment: I'm still don't really know how this platform work but thank you for the one that answering my question. Yes, I need to find the (i) but I forgot and I don't really understand when my teacher give me a short form of calculation work to get the answer. Thank You so much to you. You had helped me a lot. Please bear with me because I had a feeling that I will ask a lot of stupid question in the future.